# move up and down a treeview

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview, ttk

I'm populating a tkinter treeview in python using Os.walk() but after populating it I want to be able to reorder the tree leaves using buttons.

The command for moving up the tree works just fine (I want to be able to move multiple leaves at once)

```
def moveUp():
    leaves = Tree.selection()
    for i in leaves:
        Tree.move(i, Tree.parent(i), Tree.index(i)-1)
```

But when I reversed it to go down the tree I get a weird bug

```
def moveDown():
    leaves = Tree.selection()
    for i in leaves:
        Tree.move(i, Tree.parent(i), Tree.index(i)+1)
```

I can only move a single leaf down, if I select an odd number of leaves then the lowest one moves down, and if I pick an even number of leaves none of them move.

Comment: I suspect the problem is that when you move something up, the index of everything below changes. Try traversing `leaves` in reverse order to see if that helps.

Comment: How would I traverse the leaves in reverse order?

Answer (score 4):

As suggested in the comments going through leaves in the reverse order using reversed() fixes the problem. (Would be a comment but I don't have the reputation)

```
def moveDown():
    leaves = Tree.selection()
    for i in reversed(leaves):
        Tree.move(i, Tree.parent(i), Tree.index(i)+1)
```

Comment: No need for this to be a comment. If the user who commented a solution chooses to not write it as an answer, it's totally fine for someone else to do so instead. Especially if that other person provides a code example, as you do.

Answer (score 0):

Note, for `moveUp`, reversing the leaves would result in nothing actually changing in the tree. Simply iterating through the leaves in order is the ticket.

```
def moveUp():
    leaves = Tree.selection()
    for i in leaves:
        Tree.move(i, Tree.parent(i), Tree.index(i)-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

A corner case must be handled.

If multiple entries are selected and moved up or down, items within the selection gets moved. To handle this corner case,

```py
def moveUp():
    leaves = Tree.selection()
    # if more than 1 item is selected and the selection hit the top, do nothing
    if len(leaves) > 1 and Tree.index(leaves[0]) == 0:
        return
    for i in leaves:
        Tree.move(i, Tree.parent(i), Tree.index(i)-1)


def moveDown():
    leaves = Tree.selection() 
    # if more than 1 item is selected and the selection hit the bottom, do nothing
    if len(leaves) > 1 and Tree.index(leaves[-1]) == len(Tree.get_children())-1:
        return
    for i in reversed(leaves):
        Tree.move(i, Tree.parent(i), Tree.index(i)+1)
```